I'm getting `Error: Attribute failed policy validation.` when running `ip link add`. Why?
I run this command:
ip link add dev proof_of_concept_virtual_network_interface type veth

and I get this error message:
Error: Attribute failed policy validation.

The error is not descriptive or helpful whatsoever.

That happens because the name is too long. Apparently, it can't be longer than 16 characters.
If you run the command with peer with a long name for the peer interface, you will get another error message:
Command:
ip link add dev proof_of_concept_virtual_network_interface_1 type veth peer name proof_of_concept_virtual_network_interface_2

Output:
Error: argument "proof_of_concept_virtual_network_interface_2" is wrong: "name" not a valid ifname

